# Delete all files except the newest 3 in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ls, purge

**Question:** How do you delete all files in a directory except the newest 3?

Finding the newest 3 files is simple:

```
ls -t | head -3
```

But I need to find all files except the newest 3 files. How do I do that, and how do I delete these files in the same line without making an unnecessary for loop for that?

I'm using Debian Wheezy and bash scripts for this.

Comment: `ls` is actually the wrong tool for the job -- see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. If you have GNU find, you can do much better with a `-printf` format string that has the timestamp (ideally in UNIX time for `sort -n -z`), a separator, and then a NUL following; that way even filenames with newlines won't throw it off.

Comment: I'd also disagree that using a loop here is unnecessary. Doing things correctly and robustly isn't the same as doing them tersely, but anything else is... well... incorrect.

Comment: Also see [Get most recent file in a directory on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1015678/4154375).

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This will list all files except the newest three:

```
ls -t | tail -n +4
```

This will delete those files:

```
ls -t | tail -n +4 | xargs rm --
```

this does not delete dotfiles. if you also want to delete dotfiles then change `ls -t` to `ls -At`.

the double dash (`--`) after `rm` is a safeguard against filenames starting with dash. see here for more info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-delete-a-file-whose-name-begins-with-hyphen-a-k-a-dash-or-minus

this command can fail horribly if the filenames contain spaces or newlines or other funny characters. if your filenames can contain space, or if you plan to use this in a script then you should read these articles:  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003

Comment: @DevilsChild: Depends on whether you care about being correct. If you don't care, just pipe to xargs... but don't **ever** do that if it's anything important (like backup scripts).

Comment: @DevilsChild I've literally seen TB of backups deleted because a buffer overflow created a file with garbage in its name, and someone had assumed that since filename creation was programmatic that unusual names could never happen. Taking shortcuts can bite you hard.

Comment: What is the purpose of the double dashes `--` in the `rm` command?

Comment: it is a safeguard against filenames starting with a dash or minus. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-delete-a-file-whose-name-begins-with-hyphen-a-k-a-dash-or-minus

Comment: Very elegant solution :)

Comment: In case you are not working in the current directory, you can output full path from ls like this:

`ls -d /path/to/directory/* | sort -nr | tail -n +4 | xargs rm --`

Comment: To cover the file that has spaces in file name, use this: ``ls -t | tail -n +4 | xargs -d "\n" -I {} rm {}``

Answer (score 35):

### Solution without problems with "ls" (strange named files)

This is a combination of ceving's and anubhava's answer.
Both solutions are not working for me. Because I was looking for a script that should run every day for backing up files in an archive, I wanted to avoid problems with `ls` (someone could have saved some funny named file in my backup folder). So I modified the mentioned solutions to fit my needs.

My solution deletes all files, **except** the three newest files.

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\n' |
sort -t $'\t' -g | 
head -n -3 | 
cut -d $'\t' -f 2- |
xargs -r rm
```

Some explanation:

`find` lists all files (not directories) in current folder. They are printed out with timestamps.
`sort` sorts the lines based on timestamp (oldest on top).
`head` prints out the top lines, up to the last 3 lines.
`cut` removes the timestamps.
`xargs` runs `rm` for every selected file, while `-r` lets it not fail when no files are found

For you to verify my solution:

```
(
touch -d "6 days ago" test_6_days_old
touch -d "7 days ago" test_7_days_old
touch -d "8 days ago" test_8_days_old
touch -d "9 days ago" test_9_days_old
touch -d "10 days ago" test_10_days_old
)
```

This creates 5 files with different timestamps in the current folder. Run this script first and then the code for deleting old files.

Comment: Worked like a charm for my script !

Comment: I like this script, but what happens when the filter doesn't catch any files? in my limited testing, `rm` exits with non-zero. As a test, run the file creation above and then the script, but use a value of `-8` in the `head` command. This returns no values, which makes `rm` exit with an error.

However, it seems that the `-f` flag on `rm` will make it exit with 0, even if there were no results. So the last line could be modified as `xargs rm -f`, if you need the script to exit cleanly on no results.

Comment: You can alternatively add the "-r" option to xargs  to handle that case as well.

Comment: You are using the tab as delimiter. Won't a filename with tab in it break it?

Comment: How does the `head -n -3` work if you have linefeeds in the filenames? I think you should use null separated strings and e.g. `head -z -n -3` instead.

Answer (score 10):

The following looks a bit complicated, but is very cautious to be correct, even with unusual or intentionally malicious filenames. Unfortunately, it requires GNU tools:

```
count=0
while IFS= read -r -d ' ' && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  (( ++count > 3 )) && printf '%s\0' "$filename"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %P\0' | sort -g -z) \
     | xargs -0 rm -f --
```

---

Explaining how this works:

- Find emits `<mtime> <filename><NUL>` for each file in the current directory.
- `sort -g -z` does a general (floating-point, as opposed to integer) numeric sort based on the first column (times) with the lines separated by NULs.
- The first `read` in the `while` loop strips off the mtime (no longer needed after `sort` is done).
- The second `read` in the `while` loop reads the filename (running until the NUL).
- The loop increments, and then checks, a counter; if the counter's state indicates that we're past the initial skipping, then we print the filename, delimited by a NUL.
- `xargs -0` then appends that filename into the argv list it's collecting to invoke `rm` with.

Comment: did you miss `-0` in xargs? also, you may skip the first three by using group and dummy read: `{ read; read; read; while ... done; } < <(find ...)` this will avoid the need for a counter.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, yes, but they need to be dummy reads with `-d ''`, which makes them long enough that I went for the counter. Good catch on the `-0`; I only tested prior to that point.

Comment: Would `IFS=' ' read -r -d '' stamp filename` work instead of the (separate) dummy read?

Comment: I would appreciate more of an explanation of how this works, especially because my OS X system doesn't take the `-printf` arg to `find`. In particular, how does the `%M@` _"File's  permissions  (in symbolic form, as for ls)"_ help?

Comment: @StephenP, ...oops -- did I not backport that fix? Had it over to mtime locally.

Comment: @EtanReisner, yes, it should, but with the possible caveat of trimming trailing whitespace off the end of filenames.

Comment: @StephenP, ...unfortunately, this isn't so easy to implement correctly without GNU tools; the easy solution that doesn't require `find -printf` uses `stat --format`, which is likewise a GNUism... as is, of course, `sort -z`. I'd almost be tempted to lean on perl, if needing to support other platforms while retaining correctness.

Comment: Thanks for the edit with the explanation, I'd upvote a 2nd time for it.  I tried using `xargs -0 ls -l --` for non-destructive testing and I needed to change to `(( count > 3 ))` for keeping 3 newest files, and could change to `if (( ++count > 3 )); then`... to eliminate the separate increment.

Comment: @StephenP, good suggestion re: incorporating the increment into the test.

Comment: Do you have any reasons for not `rm`ing the file inside the while loop, instead of the `printf/xargs` combo?

Comment: And by the way, you need to repeat `IFS=` for the second `read`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, only reason is to avoid the number of external command invocations, calling `rm` once per times MAX_ARGV fills up being faster than once per call. Good catch on the missing `IFS=`.

Comment: Maybe reverse the sort? Newest files will have bigger dates, so the order must be descending (since we are keeping the first three on that list).

Comment: This will not work, because `sort -n` does not sort floating point numbers correctly. Use `sort -g` instead.

Comment: "Does not work" is a little strong -- the general use case is one where sub-second precision doesn't matter (and on many filesystems, subsecond precision isn't even there in the input data to start with) -- but since we're already dependent on GNU tools, there's no harm to the change.

Comment: What about using `head -z -n -3` and `sed -z 's/^.* //'` to get the list to feed to `xargs`?

Comment: @mbirth, you'd want it to be `sed -z 's/^[^ ]* //'` to not mangle filenames with spaces, but otherwise, looks solid to me.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, forgot about the greediness of sed.

Answer (score 9):

```
ls -t | tail -n +4 | xargs -I {} rm {}
```

If you want a 1 liner

Comment: Is this safe against files with funny names?

Comment: If you mean names with * in the middle, I would say no.  Use the find command to locate those.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `ls -t` as it is unsafe for filenames that may contain whitespaces or special glob characters.

You can do this using all `gnu` based utilities to delete all but 3 newest files in the current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
sort -z -nrk1 |
tail -z -n +4 |
cut -z -f2- |
xargs -0 rm -f --
```

Comment: ```tail -z -n +4``` will keep 2 newest files. Don't know why I have to add +2 into number of files to be kept.

Comment: `tail -z -n +4` will get entries from 4th line onwards

Answer (score 5):

In zsh:

```
rm /files/to/delete/*(Om[1,-4])
```

If you want to include **dotfiles**, replace the parenthesized part with `(Om[1,-4]D)`.

I think this works correctly with arbitrary chars in the filenames (just checked with newline).

Explanation: The parentheses contain Glob Qualifiers. `O` means "order by, descending", `m` means mtime (See `man zshexpn` for other sorting keys - large manpage; search for "be sorted"). `[1,-4]` returns only the matches at one-based index 1 to (last + 1 - 4) (note the `-4` for deleting all but 3).

Answer (score 3):

```
ls -t | tail -n +4 | xargs -I {} rm {}
```

Michael Ballent's answer works best as

```
ls -t | tail -n +4 | xargs rm --
```

throw me error if I have less than 3 file

Comment: You want to pass `-r` to `xargs` or it will execute the command without parameters if the pipeline has no input. Unfortunately, `-r` is a GNU extension so it will not work with plain old POSIX compatible `xargs`.

Answer (score 2):

## Recursive script with arbitrary num of files to keep per-directory

#### Also handles files/dirs with spaces, newlines and other odd characters

```
#!/bin/bash
if (( $# != 2 )); then
  echo "Usage: $0 </path/to/top-level/dir> <num files to keep per dir>"
  exit
fi

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' dir; do
  # Find the nth oldest file
  nthOldest=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@\0%p\n' | sort -t '\0' -rg \
    | awk -F '\0' -v num="$2" 'NR==num+1{print $2}')

  if [[ -f "$nthOldest" ]]; then
    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -newer "$nthOldest" -exec rm {} +
  fi
done < <(find "$1" -type d -print0)
```

## Proof of concept

```
$ tree test/
test/
├── sub1
│   ├── sub1_0_days_old.txt
│   ├── sub1_1_days_old.txt
│   ├── sub1_2_days_old.txt
│   ├── sub1_3_days_old.txt
│   └── sub1\ 4\ days\ old\ with\ spaces.txt
├── sub2\ with\ spaces
│   ├── sub2_0_days_old.txt
│   ├── sub2_1_days_old.txt
│   ├── sub2_2_days_old.txt
│   └── sub2\ 3\ days\ old\ with\ spaces.txt
└── tld_0_days_old.txt

2 directories, 10 files
$ ./keepNewest.sh test/ 2
$ tree test/
test/
├── sub1
│   ├── sub1_0_days_old.txt
│   └── sub1_1_days_old.txt
├── sub2\ with\ spaces
│   ├── sub2_0_days_old.txt
│   └── sub2_1_days_old.txt
└── tld_0_days_old.txt

2 directories, 5 files
```

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to the [answer by flohall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47593062/5276779). If you want to remove all folders except the newest three folders use the following:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%T@\t%p\n' |
 sort -t $'\t' -g | 
 head -n -3 | 
 cut -d $'\t' -f 2- |
 xargs rm -rf
```

The `-mindepth 1` will ignore the parent folder and `-maxdepth 1` subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `find` instead of `ls` with a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\n' |
sort -t $'\t' -g |
tail -3 |
cut -d $'\t' -f 2-
```

`find` searches the files and decorates them with a time stamp and uses the tabulator to separate the two values. `sort` splits the input by the tabulator and performs a general numeric sort, which sorts floating point numbers correctly. `tail` should be obvious and `cut` undecorates.

The problem with decorations in general is to find a suitable delimiter, which is not part of the input, the file names. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14491156/402322) uses the NULL character.

Answer (score -2):

**Below worked for me:**

`rm -rf $(ll -t | tail -n +5 | awk '{ print $9}')`

Comment: This has a number of problems. `ll` is not a standard command, though it's frequently aliased to `ls -l` in beginner-oriented distros; but why request a long-form listing only to (not quite successfully) throw away the information provided by the long listing? Even for file names which don't contain whitespace, this has all the other problems of [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and, of course, `rm -rf` is not really at all correct for the use case in the question, and potentially quite hazardous here.