# Linux command to delete all the files older than the latest modified file/s

Tags: linux, bash, shell

**Question**: How to delete all the files that are older than the latest modified file/s

The following one line command will find and delete all files except the latest 6 - but I am unable to figure out how to delete all files that are older than the latest file/s (there can be several latest files) -

```
ls -t | tail -n +6 | xargs rm --
```

**Details:**
I would like to delete all the files that are older than the latest modified file date. It doesn't matter how many days it is older - as long as it is older than latest modified file, it needs to be deleted (100 days or 1000 days or 1 day or even 1 min older than the latest modified file).

```
Dir-
File 1 6/10/2019 9:40am
File 2 6/10/2019 9:37am
File 3 6/10/2019 9:40am
File 4 2/12/2019 12:39pm
File 5 7/01/2002 11:38pm
```

From this dir, after running the command, I should be able to only see File 1 and 3, all other files should be deleted regardless of how old those file are when compared the latest modified file/s.

Comment: it would be nice if someone can comment when they downvote a question as it would help the OP understand whatever is wrong in the question

Comment: I didn't downvote, but why should you only be able to see files 1 and 3 and not 2?

Comment: File 2 is 9:37am which is older than File 1 & 3 are modified/added at 9:40am

Comment: I did not downvote either but people here want to see what you've tried so far..Your post contains no code so I bet that is why it was downvoted...

Comment: Thanks @GoinOff, I will update my question.

Answer (score 2):

The following should do:

```
newest=$(ls -Art | tail -n 1) && \
for f in *; do if [ "$f" -ot "$newest" ]; then rm -- "$f"; fi; done
```

Only restriction: newest file name must not contain newline.

This solution is not duplicate to [Delete all files except the newest 3 in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765163/delete-all-files-except-the-newest-3-in-bash-script) because only using

```
tail -n
```

does not recognize if there are two or more newest files (with exactly the same modification time). That's why using

```
[ "$f" -ot "$newest" ]
```

here.

Comment: Files should not contain any blanks at all?

Comment: Why wouldn't that work if it has blanks? I'm trying to understand how blanks are related to your command?

Comment: If the newest file contains newline, then the `tail` will cut off part of the name.  Avoiding all whitespace does seem like over-egging the caution, though (once the command is changed to `rm -- "$f"`, of course).

Comment: Newest file *name*, presumably