# How to find the images in a directory but order it first

Tags: bash, shell, csv, woocommerce

How do I sort the folder before I find all the images in it?

My folders looks like this:

- {sku-num}-{productname}
- {sku-num}-2{productname}
- {sku-num}-3{productname}

For example:

```
: 123456-myproduct.jpg
: 123456-2-myproduct.jpg
```

So the 'main' or featured image is always the first one, all other images are numbered.

I have a txt file with all sku's where I'm looping through all files to search all the images. But when I execute, I get all images in the wrong order.

I want this

```
123456, 123456-myproduct.jpg, 123456-2-myproduct.jpg
```

But half the time I get it reversed, meaning I get the second image in the position what would be the 'main' image.

This is my current code

```
while read p; do

    final="$p"

    for i in `find /Users/user/Desktop/img_sorted -name *$p* ` 
        do final+=", $(basename $i)"
    done

    echo $final

done </Users/user/Desktop/img/skus.txt
```

I need my folder to be sorted so I can just simply get the first image.

Comment: Sound like you need `sort`. This may help you: https://askubuntu.com/a/662383/169878

Comment: You can use sort(1), or use ls(1). Try also to read here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14491020/7332147